# Shut down the laptop!

Tags: computer-puzzle, situation

Here's a computer based riddle for all the linux geeks out there:

> You just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on your shiny new laptop! The system boots you into your user and shows you the desktop. However, to your dismay, the drivers for your touchpad, USB ports, Bluetooth adapter and WiFi adapter were not installed. How would you shut this computer down?
>
> Note: you may not access any other tools. The battery is not removable, and do you seriously think you can wait for 10 hours for the battery to run out?

Note that there are multiple solutions to this problem; the one that shuts the computer off in the safest way (least data loss) is the correct one. Also note all ACPI drivers are loaded and running well.

Comment: spoiler: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oA6UB.png

Comment: Was going to post this also haha

Comment: @msh210 touchpad and USB drivers are non-functional, so your mouse doesnt work.

Comment: Is the question only about Ubuntu machines? Do answers for windows count?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb (re your comment to me) I thought that screenshot was about the power button on the laptop itself, not on-screen

Comment: well, since your ethernet adapter works, you can just login remotely, ssh or something should work. would not even require hacking skills since you know your own password. then just send a shutdown command.

Comment: @clockw0rk Your idea has some requirements: ssh service has to be run, you must have another computer to use and you must know IP address (or able to track it down)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am first time on this SE site, so maybe I don't follow rules here, but it is actually pretty easy to shut Linux computer down using only buttons/keyboard:

1. > While ACPI is on, holding down power button for 10 secs is enough to shut down
2. > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> opens text console where you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, which starts reboot cycle
3. > like previous, but log into console and run `sudo halt` on command line
4. > on graphical desktop shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> opens terminal, where you can give command `sudo halt`